# i am writing vba code to scrape data from web, I got error of Remote server Machine does not exist or is unavialable

Tags: vba

```
Sub Launch_website()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim myurl As String

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

myurl = "https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/NewBusinessPerformance"
'ie.Navigate "https://www.lifeinscouncil.org/industry%20information/NewBusinessPerformance" '

ie.Navigate myurl




'On Error Resume Next
Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
```

Comment: Your code should work. Of course, with the correct reference. On which line does the code stop on error?

Comment: FYI the correct term is ‘scrape’. To scrap means to throw away as in rubbish.